# How to show loading icon in AngularJS after amount of seconds?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loading

I want to show a loading icon IF any HTTP request is taking longer than 2 seconds. I am using the code below to show the loading icon instantly when a HTTP request is made:

```
<div data-loading id="divLoading">
    <img src="http://loadinggif.com/images/image-selection/3.gif" />
</div>

<script>
app.directive('loading', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.isLoading = function () {
                return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
            };

            scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function (v) {
                if (v) {
                    elm.show();
                } else {
                    elm.hide();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
</script>
```

Note: I am a newbie with AngularJS.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

> You can use [this spinner](https://github.com/Chevtek/angular-spinners) directive.
>   You can install as a node module also:

```
 npm install angular-spinners
```

**Usage**

```
<spinner name="testSpinner"
img-src="http://loadinggif.com/images/image-selection/3.gif"></spinner>
```

**Script**

```
**This script won't work here.So i have added a working plunk.**
```

```js
angular.module("myApp",['angularSpinners'])
.controller('ctr1', function($scope,sample, spinnerService){
   setLoading(true, "testSpinner");
   sample.sampleFn().then(function(data){
     $scope.data=data;
     setLoading(false, "testSpinner");
   })
   
   function setLoading(loading, element) {
      if (loading) {
          spinnerService.show(element);
      } else {
          spinnerService.hide(element);
      }
  }
})
.factory('sample', function($http){
  return {
    sampleFn : sampleFn
  }
  
  function sampleFn(){
    return $http.get('response.json').then(function(response){
      return response.data;
    }, function(){
      $q.reject("Failed");
    })
  }
})
```

[Sample Working Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/igkA4KR6FKSKHGaIvn9r?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Apply a delay to a function whenever a http request is going.
**Step 2:** Take a variable and define it as false in starting and try to make true after getting http response.
**Step 3:** After 2 second of delay evaluate the the above defined variable if it is false means show loading inside step 1 function.